# Necessidade de rendenização Server Side para conteúdo javascript - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, seo, web-crawler

Sabendo que a partir deste ano [o crawler do google executa javascript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.no/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), considerando a indexação de um conteúdo que é exibido usando AngularJs, ainda existe a necessidade de uma versão do mesmo conteúdo rendenizada no lado servidor para SEO ?

**Plus**: Produtos como o [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) (Allow your Javascript apps to be crawled perfectly by search engines) ainda são necessários?

Answer (score 5):

Como está no próprio artigo que você cita, de modo geral a resposta é não, desde que observados alguns detalhes:

1. Scripts em arquivos separados com acesso bloqueado (via robots.txt) não serão executados e, consequentemente, e o site não será indexado corretamente.
2. Servidores que não conseguem trabalhar com o volume de requisições exigido podem prejudicar a capacidade de renderização das páginas por parte do crawler.
3. Scripts muito complexos, ou que fogem demais da média de compatibilidade com os navegadores, podem resultar em renderizações incorretas ou imprecisas, o que é ruim tanto para o visitante quanto para o Googlebot.
4. Quando os scripts removem conteúdo das páginas em vez de adicionar, o conteúdo não pode ser indexado.

Sendo assim, a melhor resposta ainda seria a opção pelas boas práticas de desenvolvimento, com ou sem auxílio de frameworks como o AngularJS, já que este, embora mantido pelo Google, não implica necessariamente em uma renderização 100% infalível pelo Googlebot.